# SQLite transactions for readonly operations

Tags: sqlite, transactions, readonly

Sorry if this is not a clever question:
Do SQLite transactions have any sense for series of read-only operations? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are atomic.
This means that multiple queries inside a transaction return consistent data, i.e., nobody else change change the data you see.